# Merging two file based on columns and sorting

Tags: c, linux, perl, awk, merge

I have two files, `FILE1` and `FILE2`, that have a different number of
columns and some columns in common. In both files the first column is
a row identifier. I want to merge the two files (`FILE1` and `FILE2`)
without changing the order of the columns, and where there is a missing
value input the value '5'.

For example `FILE1` (first column is the row ID, `A1` is the first row, `A2`
the second, ...):

```
A1 1 2 5 1 
A2 0 2 1 1 
A3 1 0 2 2
```

The column names for `FILE1` is (these are specified in another file),

```
Affy1
Affy3
Affy4
Affy5
```

which is to say that the value in row `A1`, column `Affy1` is `1`
and the value in row `A3`, column `Affy5` is `2`

```
     v~~~~~ Affy3
A1 1 2 5 1 
A2 0 2 1 1 
A3 1 0 2 2
   ^~~~ Affy1
```

Similarly for `FILE2`

```
B1 1 2 0
B2 0 1 1
B3 5 1 1
```

And its column names,

```
Affy1
Affy2
Affy3
```

Meaning that

```
     v~~~~~ Affy2
B1 1 2 0
B2 0 1 1
B3 5 1 1
   ^~~~ Affy1
```

I want to merge and sort columns based on the column names and put a
'5' for missing values. so the merged result would be as follows:

```
A1 1 5 2 5 1
A2 0 5 2 1 1
A3 1 5 0 2 2
B1 1 2 0 5 5 
B2 0 1 1 5 5 
B3 5 1 1 5 5
```

And the columns:

```
Affy1
Affy2
Affy3
Affy4
Affy5
```

Which is to say,

```
     v~~~~~~~ Affy2
A1 1 5 2 5 1
A2 0 5 2 1 1
A3 1 5 0 2 2
B1 1 2 0 5 5 
B2 0 1 1 5 5 
B3 5 1 1 5 5
   ^~~~ Affy1
```

In reality I have over 700K columns and over 2K rows in each file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a site for getting other people to write your code for you.

Comment: I'm totally new to programming and in the learning process. I've worked with Linux, Perl and C. I know how to merge files, but my problem is merging and sorting them based on the column names at the same time and also the the high number of rows and columns that I have.

Comment: Okay, so in your example is A1 part of the actual file? Or is it just so we can refer to the first line?

Comment: It's just a reference to each row and exists in my actual file.

Comment: I found a way in R, with very few commands, but takes a very very long time to read and write my files. I find Linux, Perl and C codes to be a lot more faster.

Comment: Alright, so for the `A` file, is it so that `Affy1` refers to `1`, `Affy3` to `2` and since that file is missing `Affy2` there should be a `5` inserted there?

Comment: exactly! It is shown in the output file.

Comment: And there is a row in each file with the column names?

Comment: I don't understand the "merging" idea, but I get "appending" since the `A` set seems to have nothing to do with the `B` set. I can see you are filling missing columns with a `5`, but I do not see why the third output line is `A3 1 5 5 0 0` and not `A3 1 5 0 2 2`.

Comment: You are totally correct Weather Vane! My mistake in typing. corrected.

Comment: Filip the column names are the Affy1, Affy2, .... I can have them as a separate file (as shown) or as a header in the first row.

Comment: Never mind the huge number of columns for now. Just show your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the 5 column example, along with how you specify and interpret the column usage.

Comment: @Sarah please put the `@` in front of user names so they get flagged, thanks. You don't seem to have taken the "tour" just click "help" near the top right, and read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please make up your mind which language this (missing) code is a question about.

Comment: @WeatherVane Preferably Perl or awk. I'm open to any language that solves the question.

Comment: Please see the first comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane The two files I have are independent. Just want to sort the columns and replace the missing with a 5. So for this example I get an output with 6 rows and 5 columns (Affy1, Affy2, Affy3, Affy4, Affy5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficult part is ordering the headers when some of them appear only in one file. The best way I know is to build a directed graph using the [`Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph) module and sort the elements topologically

Once that's done it's simply a matter of assigning the values from each file to the correct columns and filling the blanks with 5s

I've incorporated the headers as the first line of each data file, so this program works with this data

#### file1.txt

```
ID Affy1 Affy3 Affy4 Affy5
A1 1 2 5 1 
A2 0 2 1 1 
A3 1 0 2 2
```

#### file2.txt

```
ID Affy1 Affy2 Affy3
B1 1 2 0
B2 0 1 1
B3 5 1 1
```

And here's the code

#### consolidate_columns.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Graph::Directed;

my @files = qw/ file1.txt file2.txt /;

# Make an array of two file handles
#
my @fh = map {
    open my $fh, '<', $_ or die qq{Unable to open "$_" for input: $!};
    $fh;
} @files;

# Make an array of two lists of header names
#
my @file_heads = map { [ split ' ', <$_> ] } @fh;

# Use a directed grapoh to sort all of the header names so thet they're
# still in the order that they were at the top of both files
#
my @ordered_headers = do {

    my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

    for my $f ( 0, 1 ) {
        my $file_heads = $file_heads[$f];
        $g->add_edge($file_heads->[$_], $file_heads->[$_+1]) for 0 .. $#$file_heads-1;
    }

    $g->topological_sort;
};

# Form a hash converting header names to column indexes for output
#
my %ordered_headers = map { $ordered_headers[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#ordered_headers;

# Print the header and the reformed records from each file. Use the hash to
# convert the header names into column indexes
#
print "@ordered_headers\n";

for my $i ( 0 .. $#fh ) {

    my $fh         = $fh[$i];
    my @file_heads = @{ $file_heads[$i] };
    my @splice     = map { $ordered_headers{$_} } @file_heads;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /\S/;

        my @columns;
        @columns[@splice] = split;
        $_ //= 5 for @columns[0 .. $#ordered_headers];

        print "@columns\n";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
ID Affy1 Affy2 Affy3 Affy4 Affy5
A1 1 5 2 5 1
A2 0 5 2 1 1
A3 1 5 0 2 2
B1 1 2 0 5 5
B2 0 1 1 5 5
B3 5 1 1 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks! 
When I try to run it I get an error on line 3. Also, the out put for the last three lines (B1, B2, B3) is incorrect.

Comment: @Sarah: What is the error, please? What version of Perl are you running?

Comment: @Sarah: My best guess is that you have a very old version of Perl which doesn't support `autodie` so I've removed that and replaced it with a work-around. And I'm sorry -- I was using the A file header names to reorder the B records; that bug is fixed now

Comment: The problem was the perl version. I fixed it and it worked :) Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For the fun of it -- HTH

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use constant {A => 1, B => 2, BOTH =>3};

# I don't read data from file
my @columns = qw(Affy1 Affy2 Affy3 Affy4 Affy5);
my @locations = (BOTH, B,    BOTH, A,    A);

my @contentA = (["A1", 1, 2, 5, 1],
                ["A2", 0, 2, 1, 1],
                ["A3", 1, 0, 2, 2]);
my @contentB = (["B1", 1, 2, 0],
                ["B2", 0, 1, 1],
                ["B3", 5, 1, 1]);

#I assume both files have the same amount of lines

my @ares  = ();
my @bres = ();
for(my $i = 0; $i < @contentA; ++$i){
  # this uses a lot of memory whith huge amounts of data
  # maybe you write this in two temp result files and cat them
  # together at the end
  # another alternative would be to iterate first over
  # file A and then over file A
  my @row_a = ();
  my @row_b = ();
  push @row_a, shift @{$contentA[$i]}; #id
  push @row_b, shift @{$contentB[$i]}; #id
  foreach my $loc (@locations){
    if(A == $loc){
      push @row_a, shift @{$contentA[$i]};
      push @row_b, 5;
    }
    if(B == $loc){
      push @row_a, 5;
      push @row_b, shift @{$contentB[$i]};
    }
    if(BOTH == $loc){
      push @row_a, shift @{$contentA[$i]};
      push @row_b, shift @{$contentB[$i]};
    }
  }
  push @ares, \@row_a;
  push @bres, \@row_b;
}

foreach my $ar(@ares){
  print join " ", @{$ar};
  print "\n";
}

foreach my $br(@bres){
  print join " ", @{$br};
  print "\n";
}

print join("\n", @columns);
print "\n";
```

Comment: The code works perfectly  with the sample, but how can I read a file instead of inputting the data? In reality I have around 700'000 columns and 2'000 rows. Thanks!